# Specifying this region to shade

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I have a plot on a set of curved axes.

I want shading from the center of the *axis* circles fading to white on the outer axis. Using `center=red` puts the center of the shading in the center of the shaded area, not the center of the diagram, and I can't combine `top color=red, left color=red, right color=white, bottom color=white`.

How can I achieve this using TikZ? My current MWE is below. 
[image]

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\shade [top color=red] (0,0) -- (6:5) arc (6:-140:5) -- (0,0);
\draw [color=blue] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (-28:1) (-56:2) (-84:3) (-112:4) (-140:5)};  \fill [fill=white] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (-28:1) (-56:2) (-84:3) (-112:4) (-140:5)};

\foreach \i in {5,...,1} {
    \node [anchor=south] at (10:\i) {W\i};
    \draw [black, dashed, very thin] ++(10:\i) arc (10:-195:\i);
}

\foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angleresult{\i * -60 };
    \pgfmathsetmacro\mylabel{\i * 60 };
    \draw [gray, dashed] (0,0) -- (\angleresult:5.5);
    \node [anchor=north] at (\angleresult:5.5) {\mylabel\textdegree};
}

\draw [black, very thick](0,0) -- (6:5);

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: shading]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) -- (6:5) arc (6:-140:5) -- (0,0);
        \shade [inner color=red, outer color=white] (0,0) circle (5);
    \end{scope}

    \draw [color=blue] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (-28:1) (-56:2) (-84:3) (-112:4) (-140:5)};  \fill [fill=white] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (-28:1) (-56:2) (-84:3) (-112:4) (-140:5)};

    \foreach \i in {5,...,1} {
      \node [anchor=south] at (10:\i) {W\i};
      \draw [black, dashed, very thin] ++(10:\i) arc (10:-195:\i);
    }

    \foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\angleresult{\i * -60 };
      \pgfmathsetmacro\mylabel{\i * 60 };
      \draw [gray, dashed] (0,0) -- (\angleresult:5.5);
      \node [anchor=north] at (\angleresult:5.5) {\mylabel\textdegree};
    }

    \draw [black, very thick](0,0) -- (6:5);

  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Layering the shading underneath the plot is neat - I guess there's no easy way to do it all-in-one (no layering required)?

Comment: @simont It isn't on a different layer. The scope is used to limit the effect of the `\clip`. Otherwise, it would affect your whole diagram and nothing outside that path would appear at all. (It would all be clipped.)

Comment: Oh. :) *facepalm* that does make sense. Thank you very much indeed.